# How to concatenate two lines from a given file?

Tags: ruby

I want to concatenate a line with another line given by a text file. How do I do that?

I've tried using an array with an index, but whenver I do `line + line[index + 1]` it doesn't concatenate the previous line with the second line.

```
def createWordList(filename)

  wordArray = Array.new

  for i in 1..6
    i = gets.chomp
    i.delete("\n\r\t")
    wordArray.push(i)
  end

  file = File.open(filename, "r+")

  wordArray.each_with_index do |item, index|
    file.puts(item)
    item += item[index + 1]
    file.puts(item)

  end

end

createWordList("words.txt")
```

Ì was expecting the `line[index + 1]` to return the next line, but it instead returned the letter at `line[index + 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't understand why and what you want to achieve this but I could figure out that basically you are looking to read/call the lines as index.

Please refer [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines).

```
=> file = IO.readlines('filename') # => ["line 1\n", "line 2\n", "line 3\n"]
=> file[2] # => "line 3\n"
```